# Android: Show progress circle like Google does in their apps

Tags: android, progress

I'm using an AsyncTask to download Images for my Listview, because I dont want the download of the Images to block my UI-Thread. While the images are being loaded, I want to show an animated progress circle in the spot, where the image will be.

But I cant find an Image of the progress circle. What is the Ressource-Id? Or is there any other way? Does someone has a link to this image?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Look at the [progress bar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html). It can work (and it does by default, AFAIR) in indeterminate mode, which means it shows a rotating circle, like the one you are asking for. I know this is not an image, but what you can do, is to place a FrameLayout instead of the image, with progress bar as the only child. Then, once the loading of the images finishes, remove the progress bar and add the image.

Comment: This suggestion works quite well - I just tried it myself. It may be fiddly depending on number of images but unless anyone comes up with the res id of the in-built spinning progress bar, it seems a pretty good approach.

Answer (score 11):

Define this a global variable `ProgressDialog pd;`

Just before launche the AsyncTask do:

```
pd = ProgressDialog.show(CurrentClassName.this,"This is the title","This is the detail text",true,false,null);
```

When its done `onPostExecute` just call `pd.dismiss();`

For more detail look at : [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)

You will have to take special considerations for it to work when you rotate the device while the dialog is up.

Answer (score 5):

This is an example of a layout file for intro activity with an image and circle progress bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/intro_description"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/intro" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleInverse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: It doesn't refresh imageviews until they are reused

Answer (score 3):

You want an indeterminate ProgressBar. Take a look at developer's website -

[ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html)